# WPF MVVM : Calling a method in view model from a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF image control which its source property is bound to a property that returns an image.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" 
       Source="{Binding Path=ImageSrc,  NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource imgToSrcConverter}}" />
```

Then I have a converter that takes the image bound to the source property and converts it into a bitmapImage. When bitmapimage download has finished I would like to execute a method in my view model so I have subscribed to DownloadCompleted event in BitmapImage. So how could I call the method in view model from the converter? would it break the MVVM principles?

**Converter**:

```
public class ImgToSrcConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Image image = value as Image;
        if (image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();

            bi.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler(bi_DownloadCompleted);

            return bi;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void bi_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Call my method in view model
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is important for your app to have `BitmapImage`, then `ImageSrc` property in view model should be of type `BitmapImage` and you won't need converter

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve? Could you elaborate a little on what exactly you're trying to do? What do you mean by "download"? What will you be doing when this "download" is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a multi-converter that accepts several values:

```
public class ImgToSrcConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Image image = values[0] as Image;
        if (image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();

            ViewModel vm = values[1] as ViewModel;
            bi.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) => 
            {
                vm.Method();
            };

            return bi;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<Image Grid.Row="0">
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" Converter="{StaticResource imgToSrcConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ImageSrc" />
            <Binding Path="." />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And no, this doesn't break the MVVM pattern as long as your testable application logic stays in the view model.

Comment: Using your solution, when property "ImageSrc" in view model is changed, the converter is reached, but now the event DownloadCompleted is never fired. Why? Maybe because bi object is destroyed once bi is returned?

Comment: I defined the event handler as an anonymous method in my sample code. Besides this, I didn't change anything. Did you put a breakpoint in the anonymous method? If the event was raised before, it will still be raised.

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint in line vm.Method(); within anonymous DownloadCompleted event. Converter method is executed but event is never raised.

Comment: Is the download ever completed? Did it ever work? Anyway, your question was about how to call a method of the view model and I believe this has been answered.

Comment: Right. I will open another thread regarding this. I accept your answer. I will put here the new link to the thread.

Comment: here is the new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814636/wpf-bitmapimage-downloadcompleted-event-never-raised

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is pass the `DataContext` directly to the converter, and then access the applicable property / method from there.

Update image xaml to:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" 
       Source="{Binding Path=DataContext,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  
                        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
                        Converter={StaticResource imgToSrcConverter}}" />
```

Then, hold a reference to your ViewModel, and call accordingly:

```
public class ImgToSrcConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private MyViewModel _dataContext;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dataContext = value as MyViewModel;
        if (dataContext != null)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;

            var image = dataContext.ImageSrc as Image;
            if (image != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();

                bi.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler(bi_DownloadCompleted);

                return bi;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void bi_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataContext?.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

**Note**, that I feel this is a bit of code-smell for MVVM, typically, you would never want your ViewModel accessible through the converter. To me, it seems like some of this logic can be loaded/maintained within the ViewModel itself rather than relying on a converter.

Comment: Using this, converter is not being called.

Comment: @user1624552 You created the resource for the converter with a key of `imgToSrcConverter` in a place that is accessible to the binding?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, I created it at the beginning of the window within Window.Resources section. Also below window resources, all the content is within a main grid in which I associate the datacontext as below: <Grid x:Name="TopGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource myViewModel}">. Maybe this is affecting and it is the cause why converter is not called?

Comment: The converter will only be invoked when the source property is updated and the DataContext property is never updated. That's why you should use a MultiBinding as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an approach using a IMultiValueConverter so you can get your image and datacontext(vievmodel) to the converter...
[WPF: MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter](https://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html)

Another way could be an EventAggregator/MessageBus and then sending a message to your ViewModel...? Though many would argue that a MessageBus can be considered as an anti pattern.
[Roll Your Own Simple Message Bus / Event Aggregator](http://brentedwards.net/roll-your-own-simple-message-bus-event-aggregator/)